# Nineties sitcom about small software company

Tags: comedy, sitcoms, identify-this-tv-show

I am trying to identify an old TV show with the following properties:

- Was broadcast in the early 1990s in South Africa, but the show likely came from the United States
- The main characters were a team of nerdy/geeky software developers working at a small development company
- Early in the show they hired a non-technical secretary which introduced the more technical minded developers to different 'normal' activities (e.g. going out for lunch, hanging out, social lives, etc).
- The owner of the software company used to jump on a trampoline in his office while thinking up new software ideas
- One of the software developers, part of the main cast, always wore sunglasses.

The show wasn't on for long, so chances are it was cancelled in the first series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're talking about [Dweebs](http://www.sitcomsonline.com/photopost/showphoto.php/photo/101902), a show described as:

> Warren ( Peter Scolari), was a young computer software writer whose programs had made him a legend in the industry. Unfortunately, he was **painfully shy and socially maladjusted** as well as eccentric ( to come up with ideas for the next " killer app," he **bounced on a trampoline in his office**). His Seattle company, Cyberbite, was staffed with 3 talented but similarly **socially inept programmers**. Karl ( Stephen Tobolowsky), the oldest dressed horribly; Vic ( Corey Feldman), who thought his **dark glasses** made him cool was constantly depressed; and Morley ( David Kaufman), who had been Vic's buddy since high school, was allergic to everything-especially women. Into their dysfunctional world came Carey ( Farrah Forke), **the sexy new office manager who knew absolutely nothing about computers but much about life**. She hired Todd (Adam Biesk), as a gofer who among other things , translated technospeak into English for her, and set out to give them real lives and some style. Despite their eccentricities, they were nice guys-they just needed help dealing with the outside world.

(Excessive emphasis my own).

Comment: The pilot episode is on youtube, but the rest never made it onto DVD.

Comment: Sounds like *The IT Crowd*, but American and 17 years ago.